# Drop specific rows in pandas from a numpy array

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe a thousands of rows long that looks like this:

```
ID  Email Address
1   ...    ... 
2   ...    ... 
3   ...    ... 
4   ...    ... 
1   ...    ... 
2   ...    ... 
5   ...    ... 
5   ...    ... 
6   ...    ...
```

what I want to do is drop duplicates of ID so there is only one ID per person. I can't use drop_duplicates() because most people don't have ID's and this drops them too (not good!)

Is there a way to remove specific rows and only keep one instance of the IDs.

I have a dataframe of all the duplicate ID I want to remove if that helps. e.g. for the example I gave above:

```
ID  Email  Address
1   ...    ...
2   ...    ...
5   ...    ...
```

Maybe there's a way to turn this to a series/array of IDs and remove from the df that way?

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: @nixon I think that blank entries are also being considered as duplicates so thousands of rows are being removed just because an ID is not present

Comment: Thanks @user8322222

Comment: @user8322222 - Please check edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need chain 2 conditions - [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with `keep=False` for all dupes with no parameter for first dupes:

```
df = df[df.duplicated(subset='ID', keep=False) & df.duplicated(subset='ID')]
print (df)
   ID Email Address
4   1   ...     ...
5   2   ...     ...
7   5   ...     ...
```

Comment: @user8322222 - Super, glad can help!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
df[df.duplicated(subset='ID')]

    ID Email Address
4   1   ...     ...
5   2   ...     ...
7   5   ...     ...
```

Comment: Hi nixon, unfortunately this seems to be dropping blank entries for ID too (same issue as drop_duplicates() I imagine)

Comment: Blank entries for ID? Please could you give an example of your desired output?

Comment: Seing that what you want from the other answer, you can simply do this

Comment: hi nixon, I was looking for the following:                                                                                      

ID Email Address 
1   ...     ...
2   ...     ...
3   ...     ...
4   ...     ...
5   ...     ...

and it was answered. Thanks for your help and time though! :D